# Opaque legend in an R plot with transparent background?

Tags: r, plot, png, transparency, legend

I'm trying to put a legend in an R plot, on top of some grid lines. I want the legend to be opaque, so that the grid lines do not show through the legend. However, I also want the whole image to have a transparent (not white) background, for display on the web.

I know I can do `bg="white"` to get an opaque legend, but it does not combine well with `png(..., bg=transparent)`. Example:

```
    png("test.png", bg="transparent")
    plot(rnorm(10))
    grid()
    legend("topright", legend="foo", bg="white")
    dev.off()
```

When this png is displayed on a website with a coloured background, the colour will show through most of the plot, but the legend will still be white. Is there a way to make the legend "opaque", so that the grid lines don't show through, but still have it transparent in the final png output?

Comment: No. You'll likely have to edit after the fact, or manually draw grid lines that don't go under the legend. Or maybe just move your legend outside the plot box.

Comment: Make the legend with a bright green background ("green" or "#00ff00") and then remove this colour in some other program. I know Gimp has a 'Colour to alpha' function that will do this smoothly.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to generate these graphs programatically, so manual editing is not really an option.

Comment: MrFlick's comment didn't mean literally draw manually, just that you'd need to add a few lines of code to draw line segments on each graph